# Do these nested ExecutorServices make sense in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice

I stumbled across some legacy code and found this expression in connection with some async database handling:

```j
ExecutorService SERVICE = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

SERVICE.execute(() - > {
  try {
    SERVICE.execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // do stuff
      }
    });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

My question is, is there any reason for calling `execute()` twice on the `ExecutorService`? Wouldn't it be easier to just run:

```j
  try {
    SERVICE.execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // do stuff
      }
    });
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: nope, that's completely pointless.